# ColdFusion implement Azure Service Bus topic message Sender/Receiver

Tags: java, java-8, coldfusion, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have created a java application to send/receive the topic messages using `Azure Service Bus java SDK` and it is working perfectly fine if I run it as a Java Application.

I exported the application as `jar` along with all the dependency jars to the `{ColdFusionInstallation}\cfusion\lib` and restarted ColdFusion Application Server.

I am able to create the class objects and see their definitions while dumping but when I trying to call any particular method from the class, it's taking forever.

```
<cfset objSender = createObject( "java", "com.test.Sender" ).init()>
<cfset objSender.sendAsync( JavaCast( "string", "cftest" ) )>
```

**Sender.java**

```
package com.test;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.IMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ITopicClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.Message;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.TopicClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ConnectionStringBuilder;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ServiceBusException;

public class Sender {

    private final String namespaceConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb.......";
    private final String namespaceTopicName = "test";
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();


    public CompletableFuture<Void> sendAsync( String message ) {

        // Get client
        ITopicClient topicClient = this.createTopicClient( this.namespaceTopicName );

        // Send Async
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = topicClient.sendAsync(
            new Message( message )
        ).thenRunAsync( () -> {
            try {
                topicClient.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info( "Unable to close topic client!" );
            }
        } );
        return future;
    }

    private ITopicClient createTopicClient( String topicName ) throws RuntimeException {

        // Create client for topic
        ITopicClient topicClient = null;
        try {

            // Create
            topicClient = new TopicClient(
                new ConnectionStringBuilder( this.namespaceConnectionString, topicName )
            );
        } catch ( InterruptedException | ServiceBusException e ) {
            logger.info( "Unable to client for topic: " + topicName );
            throw new RuntimeException( "Unable to create client for topic: " + topicName );
        }
        return topicClient;
    }

}
```

I am not sure what is wrong as it is working when running directly.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mention that the call from CF is "taking forever". Does it eventually work or is some error being thrown?

Comment: @Miguel-F No, it doesn't work and no error is being thrown either.

Comment: @Beginner - When you say doesn't work, you mean it's not sending messages? Check the log files. Also, I usually don't put the dependencies in \lib as it's easy to accidentally overwrite one of CF's core jars with a different version.

Comment: @Ageax No, it is not sending the message. In my case none were updated but I will keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: @Beginner - Sorry, misread the last half. If the current code doesn't update the logs, I'd add some additional logging statements so you have an idea where it's hanging.

Comment: @Ageax I will try that.

Comment: Are both versions (Java and ColdFusion) running on the same server? If not, this could be a firewall issue.